# Entity Framework: The 'IngramMicro_RetailPrice' property on 'IngramMicro' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv, invalidoperationexception

I am using Entity Framework Code First approach - TPH to read CSV's into SQL Server. The files are read in and mapped to specific properties of specific Distributor Objects. I can successfully read in a specific file from the distributor: 'IngramMicro' and store it in the db. However once that distributor is in the db, any attempt to read in any CSV's from any distributors throws this exception:
    System.InvalidOperationException: The 'IngramMicro_RetailPrice' property on 'IngramMicro' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Decimal'

IngramMicro has this property:
    public decimal IngramMicro_RetailPrice { get; set; }

SQL stores it as a float.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the essential lines of your CSV file and the relevant code. Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dealing with NULL values on that property. Change the type from decimal to **decimal?** (nullable decimal).

SQL data type should be decimal too.

Comment: I have tried changing it to decmial? and got the same error.

Comment: decimal? (nullable decimal) and SQL data type to decimal.

Comment: Yes making it nullable ' decimal? ' get the same error.

Comment: have you changed the sql data type to decimal too?

Comment: When I attempt to modify the column it says the data type is decimal(18,0)

Comment: It shouldn't be decimal(18,0), set it to decimal(18,2) for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that manually changing the data type to decimal(18,2) in SQL Server fixed the problem. Thank you Francisco!